# Why won't a certain .cpp file compile?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, g++, mingw

I have tried in vain to find a solution to my problem. Any help is much appreciated.

I installed Mingw a while ago in an effort to begin coding without an IDE. I am trying to learn C++ and a file that I have wont compile. The file is a .cpp file that is part of an online course I am taking and compiles successfully in Visual Studio 2015, but not with the standard g++ command I use to compile within cmd.

Here is the code:

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    int ia[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    for( auto i : ia ) {
        printf("i is %d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I try compiling, the command prompt returns the following:

```
cpp112.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
cpp112.cpp:9:15: error: 'i' does not name a type
     for( auto i : ia ) {
               ^
```

I thought it could be that my compiler was out of date, but no updates showed when I opened the MinGW install gui.

Again, thank you for your assistance. I am out of ideas.

Comment: Try adding `-std=c++11` to your compiler flags.

Comment: This question is quite well written. It's got a minimal complete example that illustrates the problem and a clear error message to go with it. Anyone can trivially see exactly what problem the OP was facing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax that you used appeared in the C++ 11 standard, so you should ensure two things: your g++ compiler version supports it (all modern compilers do it) and you have specified that C++ 11 standard should be used. E.g.

```
g++ cpp122.cpp -std=c++11
```

You can also try -std=c++14 for C++ 14 features.

For g++ before version 6.1 the default mode was -std=gnu++98.  Since 6.1 the default mode is `-std=gnu++14`